The While loop present in PowerShell code blocking the PowerShell GUI from being responsive
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
 
$ffmpegPath = "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
$outputFilePrefix = "output"
$recordDuration = 10  
$global:ffmpegProcess = $null
$global:recordingInProgress = $false

function Start-Recording {
    $global:recordingInProgress = $true
    $recordIndex = 1
    while ($global:recordingInProgress) {
        $outputFile = "$outputFilePrefix$recordIndex.mp4"
        $processStartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        $processStartInfo.FileName = $ffmpegPath
        $processStartInfo.Arguments = "-f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 2 -r 30 -t                                                                                             $recordDuration -y $outputFile" 
        $processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
        $processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
        $processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = $false
        $global:ffmpegProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
        $global:ffmpegProcess.StartInfo = $processStartInfo

        try {
            $global:ffmpegProcess.Start() | Out-Null
             $global:ffmpegProcess.WaitForExit(($recordDuration + 1) * 1000)   
             if (-not $global:ffmpegProcess.HasExited) {
                $global:ffmpegProcess.Kill() 
            }
        $recordIndex++
        } catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
         } catch {
            Write-Host "Unexpected error: $_"
        }
    }
}
# Define function to stop recording
function Stop-Recording {
    $global:recordingInProgress = $false
}


I am using ffmpeg tool to work on a screen recording project. When clicked on Start-Recording button, it should continue to record the screen and should produce 10 seconds video clips till the Stop-Button is clicked. For the above code, the process of generating video clips happening but during the process the GUI is being unresponsive to stop the whole process from the GUI.The while loop is going infinite but I am unable to figure out how to stop it by clicking the Stop-Button.
Any other ways or tools suggestion to work on also welcome...

Displaying form modally with .ShowDialog() puts WinForms in control of the foreground thread. You cannot perform long-running operations in an event handler without freezing the UI. If feasible, the simplest solution is to break the long-running operation into small steps between which you must call [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents(). A better, but more complex option is to run the long-running operation in parallel, either via a job or a separate runspace using the PowerShell SDK. See this answer for details.

As an aside: Using the $global: scope is best avoided, because global variables linger even after the script exits (they are session-global).
In a script file (.ps1), you can define variables directly in the script's scope (the top-level scope) and refer to them from child scopes (e.g. in functions) via the $script: scope specifier (if you only need to read such variables, you don't even need that).
